# SQL query for multi-set classification

Tags: sql, postgresql, set, multiset

I have three tables in the database:

```
CAR_TAG
CAR_FILE_TAG
CAR_FILE
```

In the `CAR_TAG` table, I have tag names, such as:

"sedan", "SUV", "coupe", "convertible", "hatchback", "Toyota", "Ford", "BMW", "Volkswagen", "Honda", "hybrid", "electric", "4x4", "large trunk capacity", "with navigation system"

The `CAR_TAG` table looks like this, where we have all the tags listed, and each tag has an associated ID.

Example:

| ID | DESCRIPTION_TAG |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | coupe |
| 2 | with navigation system |
| 3 | sedan |

In the `CAR_FILE` table, we have various columns with different names, which are not relevant for the current task. For example:

| ID | NAME | SIZE | COLOR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BMW M3 | 4 | black |
| 2 | Honda Civic 4 | 4 | white |
| 3 | Jaguar | 2 | black |

In the `CAR_FILE_TAG` table, we have a table that connects when a tag is assigned to a `CAR_FILE`.

For example, for ID 1 in `CAR_FILE`, we can assign the tag "with navigation system". In that case, the `CAR_FILE_TAG` table would have an entry:

| ID | CAR_TAG_ID | CAR_FILE_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |

How to write an SQL query that displays all IDs from the `CAR_FILE` table that have tags belonging to more than one set from the specified list below.

- **Car types**:
  sedan,
  SUV,
  coupe,
  convertible,
  hatchback,
- **Car brands**:
  Toyota,
  Ford,
  BMW,
  Volkswagen,
  Honda,
- **Technical features**:
  hybrid,
  electric,
  4x4,
  with a large trunk capacity,
  with navigation system,

So, if a car has a tag that belongs to more than one set, for example, has the tag "sedan" and the tag "hybrid" – tags belonging to two different sets. If it belongs to three sets as well. If tags are only from one set, then we do not include it.

It's a one-to-many relationship in terms of the database architecture; one car can have multiple different tags. Here, I would like to find cars that have tags assigned from more than one set.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to do this right, then it looks like you need a `car_tag_set` table.  Add a column, `car_tag_set_id` to your `car_tag` table.  The less correct way to do this is to hardcode the set information into your query.